# Is it possible to start pandora from another application?

Tags: android

I would like to be able to start pandora in another application on android.  Is this possible by creating an intent, and launching it?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: That would be a question for Pandora. Only their developers can tell you if there is a documented and supported Intent for starting one of their activities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you know what the classpath is! If this weren't possible you wouldn't see many launcher replacement apps on the market! I have Launcher Pro (free version) and with that I can get up a list of all Activities and their classpaths on the phone by creating an Acticity shortcut on the homescreen. You could generate your own list but this is easier (If someone knows where to look elsewhere leave a comment!). Look up the classpath to launch for Pandora and that should do it. This will, of course, only work if your user has Pandora installed.

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to simply create a custom intent to launch a Pandora URL using `android.intent.action.VIEW`?

Comment: Even though app was downloaded the intent to open url still comes up when it should see app and open. another issue trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the package name:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try
{
    String packageName = "com.example.package";
    Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
}
```